# Manual Approval in Jenkins Job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-workflow

We have a Jenkins Job which runs automated test scripts.
Now we would like to have another job triggered after successful completion of this job whose only task is to get a manual approval or rejection from QA team for manual validation of the new build.
If QA rejects the job the pipeline should stop and if QA approves the next job in the pipeline should trigger.
Any pointers to implement this case?

Comment: This plugin may work https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Promoted+Builds+Plugin

Comment: the plugin doesnt have a reject build feature...one can only approve it

Comment: The act of not approving it is implicitly the same though, isn't it?

Comment: If there is no way of rejecting it...how would we come to know whether manual QA team has actually taken an action or not. There might be a scenario where QA team has done nothing but we have no means to figure out the status that whether QA wants to reject it or QA has done nothing

Answer (score 3):

Try this workflow:

- Job A runs tests. if failed email is sent to DevTeam.
- If Job A succeeds, Job B is triggered.
- Job B sends email to QA team that contains:
- "Tests have passed, if you wish to approve click here" - the link will contain a trigger for Job C.
- Job C needs to be configured to be able to run remotely. Look into using: "Trigger builds remotely (e.g., from scripts)" under job's "Build Triggers". you will be provided with a link similar to "/job/Job%20C/build?token=MY_TOKEN" which you can then use as a link in Job B's email.

Comment: What action do you want to trigger on reject?

Comment: The Rejection would trigger nothing but it is a way to let us know that the manual testing is not satisfied.If there is only an approval option, how would be come to know whether the Manual QA team has actually taken an action or not.

Comment: Kind of "Hacky", but it would work.
Create Job D (which is triggered on reject - similar to how Job C is triggered) which all it does is send an email to dev that its been rejected - you can add additional steps like removal of the artifact published, etc) - I don't see a nicer way of doing this..

Answer (score 0):

[Jenkins Workflow](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-plugin/blob/master/README.md) (mentioned in your tag, perhaps unintentionally?) is designed for this kind of thing. You can write the whole pipeline in one job with a short script.